# jQuery: How to check if an element exists and change css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First of all, sorry if this is a simple question. I am new to jQuery and I want to know how can I check if an element exists and if it does, change the css property.

Here is what I mean: I have the following list:

```
<ul class="element-rendered">
    <li class="element-choice">Item A</li>
    <li class="select-inline">Item B</li>
</ul>
```

I want to know how can I check if the class `select-inline` exists inside `element-rendered` and if it does, how can I change the css background of `element-choice` to blue?

I created a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/hjpng78s/)** to reproduce this example.

Again sorry if this is a simple question but I am new to jQuery.

Comment: `if($('.element-rendered .select-inline').length) { $('.element-choice').css('background', 'blue'); }` Check updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hjpng78s/1/)

Comment: Hey @Tushar thank you again! You are always helping me here! haha! That worked. Would you mind answer that so I can mark as correct?

Comment: `$('.element-rendered .select-inline').css("background-color", "red")` will (almost) be a no-op if the element is not found in the DOM. You could go without checking the existance at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.length` to check if the element exists in DOM.

`$('.element-rendered .select-inline')` will select all the elements having class `select-inline` inside the element with class `element-rendered`. `.length` on selector will return the number of matched elements. So, number greater that one, means the element exists. Then you can use `.css` to set inline styles.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hjpng78s/1/)

```js
if ($('.element-rendered .select-inline').length) {
  $('.element-choice').css('background', 'blue');
}
```

```css
.element-choice {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="element-rendered">
  <li class="element-choice">Item A</li>
  <li class="select-inline">Item B</li>
</ul>
```

---

I'll also recommend you to use class in CSS and add it to the element by using `addClass`.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hjpng78s/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var eR = $(".element-rendered");
if (eR.find(".select-inline").length > 0){
  eR.find(".element-choice").css("color", "blue");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work for your specific example.

Find the select-line element which is a child of element-rendered. 
The find all of the sibling elements with class element-choice and apply the css.

```
$('.element-rendered>.select-inline').siblings('.element-choice').css('background','blue')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/hjpng78s/3/

Answer (score 1):

To check if element exists could use `.is()` , or as suggested by @Tushar `.length`

```
var container = $(".element-rendered");
// alternatively `!!$(".select-inline", container).length`
$(".select-inline", container).is("*") 
&& $(".element-choice", container).css("background", "blue");
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hjpng78s/6/

Comment: _if the class `select-inline` exists inside `element-rendered` and if it does, how can I change the css background of `element-choice` to blue_

Comment: I'll suggest you to use `length` instead of `is`, I think `.length` will be slightly faster than  `is`

Comment: @Tushar Added suggestion to use `.length` for performance instead of `.is()` to  post

Answer (score 0):

> How can I check if the class select-inline exists inside element-rendered and if it does, how can I change the css background of element-choice to blue?

```
if ( $(".element-rendered > .select-inline").length ) {
    $(".element-rendered > .element-choice").css({
        'background-color': 'blue'
    });
}
```

**Docs:**

- [Find the number of elements in the jQuery object.](https://api.jquery.com/length/)
- [Set one or more CSS properties for the matched element](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r0jLboyk/1/)

```
if($(".element-rendered .select-inline")[0])
    $(".element-rendered .select-inline").css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. The selector in my link doesn't match an element but it still changes the background color.

Comment: @Diptox jQuery selector returns an _Object_, and objects are always truthy, even if the object is empty

Comment: my fault , forget the [0] front of the selector