# How to keep CSS changes made with Jquery after ajax call or form call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to hide a couple of payment options on our lightspeed Ecommerce site using Jquery during a set timeframe (Between 18.00 and 24.00) and only for people living in the Netherlands.

Since i cannot alter the file of the checkout page i use document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div") to then alter the css of mentioned div's "display:block" to be set as "display:none".

I tried wrapping the code in ajaxSuccess and ajaxComplete funtion, but it did not change anything.

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function () {
$.get("https://freegeoip.app/json/", function (response) {
$("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
$("#country_code").html(response.country_code);
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  if(response.country_code=='NL' && 17 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 24){
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(2) > div").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(3) > div").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(4) > div").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(5) > div").style.display = 'none';
    } 
  if(response.country_code=='NL' && 24 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 17){
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(2) > div").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(3) > div").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(4) > div").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(5) > div").style.display = 'block';
    }
}, "jsonp");});
```

It works fine, but as soon as a Ajax form radio-button is clicked, my code stops working. Inspector says: css-change-by-time.js?20190925175433:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

This makes sense, since i guess after the ajax call is made, the div that used to be display:block is no longer there, and so it conflicts and throws the error.

I searched the entire day on the internet, but could not find a working solution.

So my actual question is:

How do i apply these changes and how do i make them stick, no matter what happens.

Comment: The best way to do this is to check if the element exists before you apply the changes. Here is a link to a similar question that has a solution you can apply. This solution is using jQuery for the dom selectors, which you should use since you are already loading it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995297/jquery-how-to-check-if-an-element-exists-and-change-css-property

Comment: For you this would look like the following,      if($("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div").length) $("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div").css('display', 'none');

Comment: And what if the element does not exist?

Comment: The line of code I gave you will handle if the element does not exist. Because if it does not exist the if statement will evaluate to false and it will not try to apply the styles to the non-existing element.

Comment: Also I don't think your second if statement will ever evaluate as true. The currentTime can not be greater than 24 and less than 17. That may be causing you issues.

Answer (score 0):

You first see the .html whether it is pointing right div or not. I am using jquery for this.

```
 $("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div").html()
```

Apply style display block if it is pointing right

```
  $("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div").css('display','block');
```

apply display none as well

```
   $("#gui-checkout-shipment-methods > div:nth-child(1) > div").css('display','none');
```

use this for all lines.